# When is proper to use <= or = assigments in Verilog

Tags: fpga, verilog, dsp

I have not clear at all this part of Verilog when using <= or when =

I have some always blocks that make some adds, subtracts and multiplies an example is like this:

```
    module Calcs 
    #
    (
        parameter RC = 24'h0186DA,
                  RV = 24'h018666
    )
    (
        input clk,    // Clock
        //SOME INPUT VALUES FOR VAL1 VAL2 VAL.....

        output reg go  
    );



    reg [63:0] val1; 
    reg [63:0] val2; 

    reg [63:0] val3; 
    reg [63:0] val4; 

    reg [63:0] ValSelected;

    reg [127:0] Mult1; 
    reg [127:0] Mult2; 

    reg [128:0] Subs; 

    reg [128:0] Mult3; 

    reg isNeg;

    reg go1;

    reg [63:0] LastVal1;
    reg [63:0] LastVal2;
    reg [63:0] LastValSelected;

    always @ (posedge clk) begin

         Is_Valid  = (val1 != 0) && (val2 !=0); 


        if (val4 >=  val3) ValSelected = val3; 
        else if (val4 < val3) ValSelected = val4; 

        if (Is_Valid) begin
            Mult1      = val2 * RV;
            Mult2      = val1 * RC;
            Subs       = Mult2 - Mult1;
            isNeg      = Subs < 0;
            if (!isNeg) Mult3 = ValSelected * Subs;
            else Mult3 = 0;
            if (Mult3 > 1) begin
                if (((val1 != LastVal1) || (val2 != LastVal2))  || (ValSelected != LastValSelected)) go1 <= 1'b1;
                else if(((val1 == LastVal1) || (val2 == LastVal2))  || (ValSelected == LastValSelected)) go1 <= 1'b0;           
            end      
        end
    end


    always @ (posedge clk) begin
        if (go1) begin
            LastVal1 = val1;
            LastVal2 = val2;
            LastValSelected = ValSelected;
            go <= 1'b1;
        end
        else go <= 1'b0;
    end
endmodule
```

There is some strange behavior when I use <= to set the value to go1 this is never executed and if I change this for = this execute always and if the if is fulfilled go1 it never comes back to 0

can someone help me to understand this?

sorry if the code has some issues there is just an example

Many Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. You might try to get a minimal working example that shows your problem. That makes it easier to see your problem or others help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is simply:

> If ***one process writes*** to a variable synchronized to an event, and ***another process reads*** the ***same*** variable synchronized to the same event, you must write using an NBA ensuring that the reading process uses the old value of the variable.

If you don't use an NBA *writing process*, there is a race condition in the *reading process* in that you don't know if it reads the old or new value.

Note that each `always` block in your example is both a reading and writing process depending on which variable we are considering synchronized to the `posedge clk` event. Also consider the processes that write to the module inputs and read the module outputs.

If you have a variable that is local to a process, it is your choice to use either assignment depending on the functionality you desire. But for combinational, blocking assignments are recommended.

Comment: So thinking of this in my logic I need to use NBA anyway this is something that i was testing few minutes ago but the reg go  it never comes back to 0, really I don't know why

Comment: First fix your issues with using non-blocking assignments inappropriately on all variables (not just "go"), then if you still have problems post a question with a complete (i.e. including the testbench) minimal example describing your problem.

Answer (score -2):

Verilog - Blocking Assignment (=)
Two Register outputs are assigned the same input, after a shared clk edge.

Verilog – Non-blocking Assignment (<=)
Two Register  outputs are cascaded, one after the other, after a shared clk edge, I.e. a clock delayed register

As promised, proof that the above is true
[Ref](https://www.quora.com/What-is-difference-between-blocking-and-non-blocking-statements-in-verilog)

[image]

Anyone who disagrees must justify.

Comment: Are you talking about combinatorial and sequential logic?

Comment: No I’m talking only about synchronous race-free events using a FF register assignments , synthesized by 2 D FF’s This is correct. Why -1?

Comment: I.e. <= is a 2 stage shift register

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Because it's wrong. The `<=` operator does not always even imply synchronous logic, and I cannot think of any situation where it would ever synthesize to multiple chained registers.

Comment: let me check for proof

Comment: You have overlooked the fact that there are three nonblocking assignments in the corresponding source. The Powerpoint slide you've included in your answer (without attribution, by the way) is trying to show that, in a clocked `always` block, **each** `<=` assignment is effectively synthesized to one register.

Comment: @duskwell  It does not matter how many assignments you have in a Nonblocking source, each clocked or synchronous event saves the last value so that others may read it before the next interval. and you missed the link which attributes the image I showed. 2 errors on your assumptions

Comment: @duskwuff  ? Better?    .......